# How to store files in android device's memory without the user being able to see it?

Tags: android

Some of the music apps lets users to download songs over internet. But the user can access those files through app only. These files are not visible in folders like downloads/gallery etc. How do they achieve it?

I am assuming storing big files in-app is not a good idea!

Comment: If the device is rooted anyone can access anything no matter where you put it

Answer (score 1):

Create your file in private folder app.

```
myPath = new File(this.context.getFilesDir(), "nameOfImage");
```

[See more - Android Developers.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html?hl=pt-br)